# Display value names from sql query within a php array

Tags: php, mysqli

I made a function in order to get all users from my database
`$allUsers = selectAllUsers($conn);`

This function is working well and var_dump give me an array like this

```
array(49) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> string(15) "Thomas Anderson" [2]=> string(16) "thomas@gmail.com" [3]=> string(4) "Thom" } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(2)
```

Now I made a foreach loop which is working well in order to display the data like this

```
<?php
  var_dump(selectAllUsers($conn));
  $allUsers = selectAllUsers($conn);
  if ($allUsers) {
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($allUsers as $key) {
    $i++;
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key[0] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key[1] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key[2] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key[3] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
   }
  }
?>
```

My fields from users database are: `users_id, users_name, users_email, users_uid`

But I want something like this in order to name the fields. Unfortunately I got an error from php `"Undefined index: users_id in"`

```
foreach ($allUsers as $key) {
    $i++;
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key["users_id"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key["users_name"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key["users_uid"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $key["users_email"] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
```

How can I manage that?

Here my function:

```
function selectAllUsers($conn)
{
    $sql = "SELECT users_id, users_name, users_email, users_uid FROM users ORDER BY users_id ASC;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
    $result = $resultSet->fetch_all();
    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should start by fetching the data from the result set as an associative array then, instead of a numerically indexed one.

Comment: Yes, use `$resultSet -> fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` to get column names. By default, it returns a numeric array as you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use associative keys then you need to fetch associative array from mysqli_result. Use this:

```
$resultSet->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

If you want to have both numerical and associative keys then you can use:

```
$resultSet->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Also, I would like to point out that your `if` statement in that function is not very useful. You can remove it. Your function can then become:

```
function selectAllUsers($conn)
{
    $sql = "SELECT users_id, users_name, users_email, users_uid FROM users ORDER BY users_id ASC;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_BOTH);
}
```